# Is it true that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ when $\int f \leq \int g$ and f,g Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that functions $f,g \in R[a,b]$ and are such that $\int^b_af \leq \int^b_ag$. Is it true that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$? Explain

I think the answer should be not necessarily, there must be somewhere it isn't true. Thinking about the truth tables/logic of $p \rightarrow q$ doesnt necessarily mean $q \rightarrow p$ I'm just stuck on finding an example of how/when it doesn't?

Comment: Can you find a function $f$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$, but $f$ takes both positive and negative values? Do you see how that gives a counterexample?

Comment: It's not true. For instance, suppose that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, *except at one point*. Then, $\int_{a}^{b} f\le\int_{a}^{b}g$.

Comment: If $g(x)=f(a+b-x)$ then the integrals are the same. Is $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x?$

Answer (score 1):

This is not always true. Take, for example, the functions:

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
f:[0,1] &\longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}\\
x & \mapsto & 2
\end{array} \ \ \ \ e \ \ \ \ \begin{array}{ccl}
g:[0,1] &\longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}\\
x & \mapsto & 12x^2.
\end{array}$$
Realize that
$$\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 2dx = 2 \ \ \ \mbox{e} \ \ \int_{0}^1 g(x)dx = \int_{0}^1 12x^2dx = 4.$$
However, $f(0) = 2 > 0 = g(0)$.

**PS:** It's good to point out that we can even think of some inequality of this type that you thought in local terms in a small neighborhood, but not for the whole range...

Comment: Thank you so much for a concrete example. Abstractly, I knew it wasn't always true in my mind, but I have a hard time creating concrete examples to prove my point and am trying to work on it.

Comment: Studying Mathematics requires time to abstract your objects. This difficulty you feel is also felt by all of us at some point with easy or difficult content. The business is always to keep studying. Hugs!